# Use docker entrypoint and cmd with fabric8

Tags: java, docker, maven, fabric8

I have container which I want to start with maven plugin fabric8
how it looks without plugin

```
docker run -it --name psql -v D:/sql:/var/sql governmentpaas/psql psql postgresql://user:password@host:port/database
```

then I run command in CLI

```
\i 'var/sql/script.sql'
```

and it works perfectly for me.

Now I am trying to do same with fabric8 plugin

```
<image>
                                    <alias>governmentpaas/psql</alias>
                                    <name>governmentpaas/psql</name>
                                    <run>
                                        <volumes>
                                            <bind>
                                                <volume>${project.build.testOutputDirectory}:/sql</volume>
                                            </bind>
                                        </volumes>
                                        <entrypoint>
                                            <shell>psql postgresql://user:password@host:port/databse</shell>
                                        </entrypoint>
                                        <cmd>
                                            <shell>\i 'var/sql/script.sql'</shell>
                                        </cmd>
</image>
```

And I get error

```
 Failed to execute goal io.fabric8:docker-maven-plugin:0.24.0:start (start): I/O Error: Unable to start container id [83f05562ec6
e] : OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: exec: "psql": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown (Bad Request:
 400)
```

How I can change command inside plugin to fix that error?

Comment: Why not use Flyway or Liquibase to run your SQL commands when the app starts?

Comment: In any case, you cannot run an interactive `CMD`  here. You would want `psql -f /var/sql/script.sql` just as the entrypoint (although the error actually says psql command isn't part of the container you ran)

Comment: @OneCricketeer but how I can do it as entrypoint, if error says that psql is not part of container?

Comment: If you run the container itself, then `/usr/bin/psql` does exist